# Trying to delete 0 columns numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to remove all the 0 columns out of the matrices in the set J_U. however i am getting this error: "index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4" i think the problem is that each matrix is being reduced in dimension every time i remove a 0 column and it wouldn't allow it go to 2*p columns. I think that is the problem but i am not sure how I could just iterate making each matrices in J_U without the 0 vectors. My actual code is slightly bigger and my J_U's have columns that are not 0's. This just a toy code, which is why it's just a matrix of 0's. I am just showing minimal code for simplicity:)! I hope this is enough! any comment is appreciated.

```
n = 5
p = 4
T = 5
J_U = {}
for i in range(n):
    J_U["J_U" + str(i)] = np.zeros((T,2*p))

for j in range(n):
  for i in range(2*p):
    if np.all((J_U['J_U' + str(j)][:,i])==0):
      J_U['J_U' + str(j)] = np.delete(J_U['J_U' + str(j)],i,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly as you described. To resolve it, you can save the index of columns you want to delete, and delete them at once:

```
idx=[]
for j in range(n):
  idx.append([])
  for i in range(2*p):
    if np.all((J_U['J_U' + str(j)][:,i])==0):
      idx[j].append(i)
  J_U['J_U' + str(j)] = np.delete(J_U['J_U' + str(j)],idx[j],1)
```

but a better solution than deleting, is selecting the columns with any non-zero value:

```
for j in range(n):
  J_U['J_U' + str(j)] = J_U['J_U' + str(j)][:,np.any(J_U['J_U' + str(j)],0)]
```

Note that `np.all((J_U['J_U' + str(j)][:,i])==0)` is the same as `np.all(J_U['J_U' + str(j)]==0,axis=1)` and same as `~np.any((J_U['J_U' + str(j)],axis=1)`.

output for your example:

```
{'J_U0': array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64), 'J_U1': array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64), 'J_U2': array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64), 'J_U3': array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64), 'J_U4': array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64)}
```